# Sending detailed Firebase data to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am new to mobile programming and I want to make a simple android app using some data stored in Firebase. I managed to create a RecyclerView with all the children of my Firebase collection and I want to press a button to navigate to a more detailed view of a specific child (for example to see a bigger image, a complete description etc). Here I am encountering a few errors. I have created an adapter, like this:

```
public class MainAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainModel, MainAdapter.viewHolder> {

    Context context;


    public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {
        //viewHolder properties initialization

        holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dresses");
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String ma = snapshot.getValue().toString();

                        String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String brand = snapshot.child("brand").getValue().toString();
                        String description = snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                        String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                        String url = snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString();
                        String price = snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString();
                        
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("dress" , String.valueOf(ma));
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

So when I am pressing the button with the id btnView I want to navigate to my Detailed Activity, which is this:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView name, brand, url, price, description;
    ImageButton fav;
    ImageView image;

    ConstraintLayout view;

    MainAdapter mainAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        name = findViewById(R.id.nameDress);
        brand = findViewById(R.id.brandDress);

        url = findViewById(R.id.urlDress);
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        price = findViewById(R.id.priceDress);
        description = findViewById(R.id.descriptionDress);

        fav = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        image = findViewById(R.id.imageDress);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dresses");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    name = (TextView) snapshot.child("name").getValue();
                     brand = (TextView) snapshot.child("brand").getValue();
                     description = (TextView) snapshot.child("description").getValue();
                     image = (ImageView) snapshot.child("image").getValue();
                     url = (TextView) snapshot.child("url").getValue();
                     price = (TextView) snapshot.child("price").getValue();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mainAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mainAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

So basically I want to find a way to send the data from my recycler view item in the main activity to my detailed activity when pressing on the view button. The problem is that the context seems to be null in my adapter, because I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

I tried to find a way to inject it in this component somehow, but I realised it's not exactly how it would normally work in Java. How should I solve this?

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: "*I know this code has probably lots of problems.*" - on Stack Overflow, you will need to distill your question down to a **single** problem that you're able to explain and illustrate with a minimal amount of code.  It's not really acceptable to paste all your code and expect someone to debug it all for you.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that and I was not expecting that, I said that it has many problems, because I wasn't expecting that to be the only one, not because I wanted to solve 30 problems at once. I specifically said the problem lies in my context and I have pasted an error, maybe I didn't put it right into words. I pasted a lot of code only if it was of any use in solving this issue, I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't initialized the context in the adapter code. The context could be initialized by passing it in the adapter constructor
   e.g.

   ```
   public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options, Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       super(options);
   }
   ```
2. To pass the "MainModel" class to DetailsActivity, you can implement Parcelable or Serializable (I would go with Parcelable since it's faster) and send the "MainModel" class via intent
   e.g.

   ```
    intent.putExtra("your_intent_key", mainModel);
   ```

And to get the MainModel class in DetailsActivity, in onCreate() you can:

```
mainModel = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("your_intent_key");
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Ok, I get it, I have initialized the context. Should I also initialize the context in my main activity code in a similar way? Because I will have to pass it when using my adapter.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after passing the context to the adapter constructor

Comment: In your DetailActivity class, you have declared the member variable "mainAdapter" but I don't see any initialization :D  e.g. mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(this)